# How to use/connect a database, EJB with TomCat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ejb, ibm-cloud

I created a simple project JAVA EE with GlassFish to implement a simple REST API. During this project, I created a jdbc pool connection (with the glassfish interface) with postgresql and use EJB and Jersey to store my data in the database. There is no problem but now I would like to do the same with Tomcat to deploy on bluemix but I don't really understand...

I created a web project dynamic with tomcat 8.5 on Eclipse, created a simple jsp file to test and deploy it on bluemix, that works ! But now I would like to connect a database to my tomcat application like before, I googled it but I don't understand if it is possible and how to do this... 
Anybody can help me please ?

Thank in advance :)

Comment: What;s your question ? How to setup the JDBC connection, or i fyou can use EJB on tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy EJBs in Tomcat because it only implements the servlet and JSP specifications from Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TomEE which is a full EE stack based on Tomcat but includes OpenEJB, OpenJpa etc. In their site you can find how to deploy TomEE as a war in a plain Tomcat in case that you want to use your existing Tomcat installation. Check the links below

[TomEE Home](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)

[TomEE deployement as war](http://tomee.apache.org/installation-drop-in-war.html)

[TomEE Datasource configuration](http://tomee.apache.org/configuring-datasources.html)